# Batch convert .wav files to .mp3 files through sub-directories then delete the remaining .wav files

Tags: batch-file, audio

I work at a radio station where we audio log using a program called Skimmer Plus that creates multiple sub directories out of our parent directory "Air Check" and the directory tree looks like this (descending):

Air Check
     Year (so right now it would be 2016)
        Month (November)
             Day (22)

And the .wav files are saved in the Day directory, but there are no files saved in any of the other directories, just in the "Day" directory.

What I am struggling with is first automatically converting the .wav files to .mp3 files. Right now I just use the lame dropper "lamedropXPd3-64.exe", but I also have "lame.exe" downloaded and available to use if that would make it easier. Here is the code I have attempted with the automatic conversion:

```
@echo off
PushD for %%i in (*.wav) do "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check\2016\November\22" -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05 "%%i" "%%~ni.mp3" & PopD
pause
```

And the error message I get is: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

So that is my first issue.

The second issue (deleting the leftover .wav files in order to save space) I'm a lot closer on getting to work. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
PushD "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check\2016\November\22" &&(forfiles -m *.wav* -d -0 -c "cmd /c del /s /q @path") & PopD
pause
```

And that works to delete all the files, but as you can see, it will only affect that day. I want it to work from this point right here:

```
@echo off
PushD "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check\" &&(forfiles -m *.wav* -d -0 -c "cmd /c del /s /q @path") & PopD
pause
```

But when I try and run that, I get the following error message: 
"ERROR: no files found with the specified search criteria."

What could I change on both parts of the code to make them fully operable?

(Also, I put the `@echo off` and `pause` in there for ease in testing, I will be taking them out when I get a final program together).

Thank you!

Comment: I would start building the command line for converting a single `.wav` file; after that, I would wrap around a [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop to process the entire directory tree (which is what I think you want); finally, I would insert a `del` command into the loop after the conversion tool (`lame`), so that it is executed only in case of conversion success (I guess `lame` returns a non-zero exit code/`ErrorLevel` in case of errors)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put some decent tips you got together, this batch will by default scan the current day folder for .wav files. But there are optional command line args to scan the whole tree down from `Base` through `/FullScan` or current `/Year` or `/Month`.

The Lame and Del commands are only `Echoed` as long as the two echo commands stay in the second last line.

```
:: Wav2mpg.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Lame="X:\Path\to\your\lame.exe"
Set LameOpts= -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05
Set "Base=\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check"

:: Get current Date
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "year=%_DT:~0,4%"&Set "Month=%_DT:~4,2%"&Set "Day=%_DT:~6,2%"
:: Strip leading zero from Month, Get Monthname
set /a Mo=100%Month%%%100
For /f "tokens=%Mo%" %%A in (
  'echo/January February March April May June^
   July August September October November December'
) do set MonthName=%%A

If /i "%~1" Equ "/FullScan" Goto :Skipover
If /i "%~1" Equ "/Year"  Set Base=%Base%\%Year%
If /i "%~1" Equ "/Month" Set Base=%Base%\%Year%\%MonthName%
If /i "%~1" Equ "" Set Base=%Base%\%Year%\%MonthName%\%Day%

:skipover
PushD "%Base%" || (Echo couldn't pushd %Base%&Pause&Exit /B 1)
For /f  "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/A-D .\*.wav'
) Do Echo %Lame% %LameOpts% "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.mp3" && Echo Del "%%~fA"
PopD
```

Comment: Wow...that is all GREAT information, and it looked like it worked. I paused in between lines so I could check the echoes, and the output showed that it ran....but I went to the physical folder, and the .wav files were still sitting there in the folder, even though in .cmd it the output showed that they were converted to .mp3s and then deleted. And then I tried running the program again and got this error message: "Files not found"

Comment: What about the echo's, did you remove them? And if yes are the mp3 created?

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot...I didn't pull the echoes. When I pulled the echoes, it all worked for the current day, but for yesterday, there are still .wav files sitting in my directory. So it works for the current day, but didn't go backward. I feel bad that I keep asking you for help on this, I'm just stuck and you've been so great, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm going to hate the android App, because it doesn't allow to send the entered message. Well nevermind - why not try to run the batch with cmdline arg `/month`. If there no more wav files it will just take the dir a bit more time. HTH

Comment: So I eliminated this line: If /i "%~1" Equ "" Set Base=%Base%\%Year%\%MonthName%\%Day%   and it worked for the day previous. Now, if I am correct (and sorry for asking what sems like a really basic question) if I eliminate <code>If /i "%~1" Equ "/Year"  Set Base=%Base%\%Year%
If /i "%~1" Equ "/Month" Set Base=%Base%\%Year%\%MonthName%</code>   That should scan the entire parent directory, correct? What I'm getting at is that I want it to work even when I leave, will I need to eliminate all those lines, so that it will continue to work in perpetuity?

Comment: I also apologize for the format, for some reason my markup (<code></code> around where I want to make it the code format) isn't working.

Comment: No to the question if running perpetually (but can be integrated). Assuming new files are only created for today, and scanning the whole tree isn't neccessary if once all old files are converted I choose the current day as default, (no cmdline arg). In what interval do new files come in?

Comment: New files come in every weekday twice a day...the first time they stop coming in at 9:02 AM and the second time they stop coming in at 6:02 PM.

Comment: IMO you should leave the batch as is (with echo removed) and schedule it to run twice a day at 0910 and 1810 and with your credentials (otherwise no network access). I feel you don't really understand the cmdline args, it means to open a cmd.exe window and run tge batch like so `X:\Path\wav2mp3.cmd /month` or any of the other options. But I think this question is answered and we're getting offtopic exchanging through comments. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
PushD
for %%i in (*.wav) do someexecutablenameherwouldbehelpfulIthink "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check\2016\November\22" -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05 "%%i" "%%~ni.mp3"
PopD
pause
```

Comment: So that helped, (my executable by the way is lame.exe, I should have made that clear, my bad), I'm not getting an error message anymore, just nothing is happening.

Comment: If you `echo someexecut...` then you should get a list of the tasks being generated. Are these correct? If you execute the exact same task from the prompt, does "something happen"? If not, what changes do you need to make to the task parameters to get something to happen?

Comment: When I echo that line, there are no tasks generated. And that is a good question, I will be thinking on that as I continue to try and get this to work.

Comment: It would mean that the current directory after the `pushd` has no `.wav` files. Perhaps `pushd "your directory with .wav files"` may assist.

Answer (score 0):

To convert all `.wav` files in your directory tree to `.mp3` files, you could use the following code:

```dos
pushd "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check" || exit /B 1
for /R %%F in ("*.wav") do (
    pushd "%%~dpF" && (
        lame -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05 "%%~nxF" "%%~nF.mp3" && (
            del "%%~nxF"
        )
        popd
    )
)
popd
```

To convert `.wav` files of today (or, more precisely said, those with a modification date of today, without checking the parent directory name), you could use the following code:

```dos
pushd "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    forfiles /S /M "*.wav" /D +0 /C "cmd /C echo @path"
') do (
    pushd "%%~dpF" && (
        lame -V 6 --vbr-old --resample 22.05 "%%~nxF" "%%~nF.mp3" && (
            del "%%~nxF"
        )
        popd
    )
)
popd
```

Note that for both approaches, successfully converted `.wav` files are deleted afterwards.

Answer (score -3):

can only recommend "EZ CD Audio Converter", using it for years, being very excited with, for converting (and also deleting in one run). Not expensive, worth every cent. There's a free 30days trial available.

For organizing, moving, tagging I recommend "mp3tag". Can work in batches and tag and move files. Great freeware, but for the full potential you have to learn the syntax.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question at all.  They are having issues with batch file scripting - not looking for software recommendations.

Comment: But it sounds like to me that I would still be stuck in the same situation: having to do everything manually. There is a lot of turnover where I work (because it is a college campus) and so when I leave I just want it to work in the background. Also, I probably wouldn't have budget for it if I had to buy something.